# Servlet page shows a 404 error, does not come up

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I'm trying to send mail using form via the **JavaMail API**. I have created a simple jsp page with my **servlet** class as the form action, a java class as the Model.  However each time I run the Jsp page to test, it shows a 404 page, saying requested resource not available when I click the "Submit" button on the form instead of redirecting to servlet.

I thought this could be a servlet mapping problem so I manually registered the servlet in a **web.xml** file I created in NetBeans but it's still not working.

The code in the servlet class is:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
<display-name>mailservlet</display-name>
<description>

</description>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mailservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class></servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mailservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mailservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

mailservlet is the name of the servlet class.

Any suggestions on what else to do would be appreciated.

Comment: In the servlet tag, i think you forgot to write the fully qualified name of the servlet class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the class name and package in the servlet-class, otherwise it won't know what class to use. e.g:

```
<servlet-class>mypackage.myclass</servlet-class>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the fully qualified name of the servlet class

```
<servlet-class>com.sample.domain.test.MailServlet</servlet-class>
```

Then you need to do a post or get request to this resource, e.g.

```
<form action="/contextroot/mailservlet" method="get">
```

in your jsp page